# ForEach Property in Get-Member

Tags: powershell, foreach, sqlcmd

I have the following snippet of code in my powershell script

```
    $sqlHDR = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=" + $dir + $m + ".xls;HDR=NO','SELECT * FROM [" + $y + "`$B1:Z1]')"
    $doHDR = invoke-sqlcmd -query $sqlHDR -ServerInstance $sqlserver -Database $db

    $doHDR | get-member -membertype properties
```

This is part of a loop that cycles through hundreds of Excel spreadsheets.  The result is a dynamically changing set of columns from F1 through to F*n* (*n* being the unknown final column number) which have only one row, with a single value in each row.

I wondered if I could use get-member to somehow loop through the columns in the dataset to gain access to the values in field?  Or am I going about this completely backwards, is there a better way to loop through the values in a single datarow?

Alternatively is there a way to loop through the property names themselves?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this help any?

```
$doHDR.psobject.properties | 
 where {$_.name -like 'something*'} |
 foreach {set-variable -Name $_.name -Value $_.value}
```

Update with example foreach

Comment: `$doHDR.psobject.properties | select value`
This appears to mostly give me what I'm looking for, is there anyway I can filter it based on `name` and then assign each value to a variable...?

Comment: Don't see any reason why not. Updated with an example that filters on name prefix, and assigns values to variables with the same names.

Comment: `foreach($prop in $doHDR.psobject.properties | select value)
{
$hdr = $hdr + $prop.Value
}`
This will string all of those values together for me, so I'm just left with how to filter them based on `name`

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it!
`foreach($prop in $doHDR.psobject.properties | ? {$_.name.StartsWith("F")} | select value)`

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use `Format-List`?

```
$doHDR | FormatList F*
```